# Closed set on topological space

Tags: general-topology

This is a  problem on topological spaces and continuous functions.

If $f,g \to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions, then $T=\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed on X

Comment: Exercise: Prove that this statement is also true for any other hausdorff space Y instead of $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Prove that the function $f-g:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto f(x)-g(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: I was typing that too haha

Answer (score 1):

$f-g$ is the difference of continuous functions, hence continuous. Then

$$(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$$

is the set in question and being the inverse image of a closed set, it is closed.

Comment: thanks, is a great solution.